# What service account does Flexible Environment use to access Datastore in another project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-flexible

Running in Flexible Environment in one project, I want to write to another project using *com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore*.

Under what "service account" does code run in Flex Environment? What permissions are needed?

Code:

```
Datastore ds = DatastoreOptions.builder().projectId("projectB").build().service();
ds.put(entity);
```

Stacktrace when  permissions are wrong.

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.translate(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.commit(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:390)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:387)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:179)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:244)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commit(DatastoreImpl.java:386)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commitMutation(DatastoreImpl.java:380)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:340)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Datastore owner permissions to

```
<source-project-name>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Note that that's the human-readable-string project *name*, **not** the numerical ID, as found in other service accounts on the pattern of *999999999999@developer.gserviceaccount.com* and the like.